# What does "voting irregularities" mean in terms of a suspension?

Tags: discussion, voting

I was looking at another user's profile (not mine!) and noticed that the account was suspended. The exact text reads:

> This account is temporarily suspended for voting irregularities. The suspension period ends in 7 days.

Now I know what happens when someone is suspended, but I'm a bit unsure about the 'voting irregularities' part. I've read a few other discussions here on meta, such as [Please don't misuse the voting system](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7240/please-dont-misuse-the-voting-system)

**How can one vote irregularly?***

<sub>*Not that I'm looking for a suspension, I just want to know what kind of voting behaviour to avoid.</sub>

Comment: Voting irregularities usually means someone has some sockpuppets that are upvoting each other.  I found one user with what looked like at least two sockpuppet accounts today, and they all got merged into one.  That's most likely the user you were looking at, I suspect.

Comment: Of the (small) list of things you can get suspended from Stack Exchange for, they are all no-brainers. Someone who is suspended really should have known (and probably actually did know) that what they were doing (spamming, racism, vote-spamming, etc) was wrong.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Voting irregularities would be repeatedly upvoting or downvoting answers from a particular user, often in a rapid fashion.  The algorithms for determining what constitutes "irregular" are intentionally undisclosed, to avoid them being gamed.  Rest assured that they are conservative enough that legitimate users should never get identified.

Comment: The algorithms are just warning bells; we and SE community managers investigate each case manually.

Comment: @badp To my recollection, the algorithms take other automatic action though right?  Just not suspension.

Comment: @EBongo You will never be suspended by an algorithm, AFAIK.

Comment: @badp I was thinking of serial vote reversal, but not sure if there was other automatic stuff.

Comment: @EBongo different set of algorithms