# Asking a question just to answer it

Tags: discussion, answers, asking

What happens with questions being asked, just to provide an answer "FAQ Style"?

I have been guilty of asking a question like this, [about the timezones for an in-game character's apperance](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/185936/what-time-zone-is-used-on-the-xur-timetable). Both the question, and the answer, received upvotes.

But then I saw [this question about how to break obsidian in Minecraft](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/190034/how-do-i-break-obsidian-in-minecraft), and my reaction was a little less inviting. The question and answer received downvotes

What is the quota for asking a question, just so you can answer it?

EDIT: To clarify, the same user asked a similar question about [the time-frame of an "Minecraft Tick"](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/189918/in-minecraft-how-much-is-a-redstone-repeater-tick). The question was downvoted (I'm assuming due to poor research effort) while my answer was upvoted, even though it was pretty much a direct cut/paste from the wiki. I also left a comment asking for a better research effort next time.

Comment: See also [this question](/questions/1204/etiquette-of-immediately-answering-ones-own-question)

Answer (score 5):

Asking and answering your own question is an acceptable and allowed thing. Admittedly, we assume you are doing so in good faith to share information, rather than say, rep-farming or whatever. In general, there aren't really rules or quota or guidelines, other than the usual stuff that applies to all questions and answers. Like [this blog post](http://blog.stackexchange.com/2012/05/encyclopedia-stack-exchange/) states,

> if you have a question that you already know the answer to if you’d
>   like to document it in public so others (including yourself) can find
>   it later it is OK to ask, and answer, your own question on a relevant
>   Stack Exchange site.

Comment: So does the content really have much to do with this practice? I.e. in the second question linked, the user is asking/answering about something that is very common knowledge by this point.

Comment: Apply this criteria: If it were asked and answered by two different people, would you object to it?

Comment: To the question; yes (as I have) to the answer; no (also the case) but I wouldn't upvote it either.

Answer (score 3):

Sharing information Q&A style is actually really welcomed on the SE Network **as long as your intention is sharing Information** and not rep-whoring.

But note: Your intention is not as important as the content of the Q&A. If the post is low quality or shows no research effort like the second question you mentioned, it will most likely get downvoted. If it's in Q&A style and it's crap it's getting downvoted even harder since it gives the impression of a bad attempt of rep-farming.

If you post a high quality Question/Answer it will obviously get upvoted because you provided useful information.  A Q&A style post that's high quality will also get upvoted because it provides useful information. Maybe sometimes you'll get a downvote or two from someone who thinks "naah he's just repwhoring". But in the end, if you make a high quality Q&A post you've earned your reputation since you've added useful information to the website. If you post crap you've earned the downvotes.

**A Q&A style post is perfectly fine if the content is high quality**. Or as perfectly shown in [this post](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7240/please-dont-misuse-the-voting-system/7241#7241): **Ignore the user when voting and focus on the content**

If you feel like someone is flooding the site with bad Q&A posts you can still flag the post for moderator attention.

Oh and also a thing to note: Q&A posts should be avoided if it's about something that's commonly known like "How do I craft a pickaxe" (Falls under poor research effort).