# How to handle a question with low effort?

Tags: discussion, questions, specific-question

This was posted recently [How do you have very cool skins on a PS4 like the creeper skin It wont let me where it](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/382040/264353), and was wondering how to handle it. I politely (I hope) commented on it asking for clarification, as I can't figure out the meaning. FIrst off, it seems like it should be tagged `minecraft-bedrock-edition` and not `mm-heroes-kingdoms`. Second of all, the title is very poorly written, and the body text makes little sense. I don't think flagging as spam is the correct path as there is no advertisment, but it is spam-like. I am not sure how to procede. Should it also be downvoted? Any help in direction would be appreciated.

Comment: Is this posted in the correct place? I figured meta was the best place, but I m not sure. And, with looking at the post again. I realized there is a 'Needs Improvement' Flag. So did that, and I guess that should be all I need to do. What a ridiculously simple thing I overlooked.

Comment: Sometimes it's not even a matter of low effort; that question appeared to simply be, no effort. You followed the right steps, and asking about it in meta is never a bad thing!

Comment: @Kaizerwolf Thanks for the info. I really enjoy the community of Arqade, and the meta is no different :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

While you can't vote to close it yet, you can still flag it: click Needs Improvement in the flagging dialog, and push the appropriate reason. This doesn't count as a vote, but simply adds it to the Close Votes review queue for >3000 rep users to look at. This would be the recommended action here, along with downvoting because it is very sloppy and no effort expended at all.

A polite comment also would not hurt, in fact, I would highly recommend doing so, as a courtesy. There's nothing worse than being told your questions are bad but not being told why; we've had some very confused and angry people<sup>[here's an example](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/15562/250180)</sup> who were surprised for getting downvoted and/or closed without those people working to help. There are [many reasons](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4155/250180) for this, all of which I disagree with, and while a lack of comments doesn't necessarily correlate to unfriendliness, I don't want people to get those connotations in the first place.

As I always say whenever I advise downvoting, please do check back after a while! Some low-quality posts do go on to become great questions if the asker has a change of heart. This doesn't happen often, but if it ever does, please do them a favour and undo your downvote, maybe even upvote if it has improved by a substantial amount. Keeping your downvote there is like scolding them when they're trying to change. Questions and answers aren't defined by their past; they can grow and change for the better.

Comment: Bookmarking or Following the post are great ways of being notified when things change on the question/answer.

Comment: @Robotnik Personally I don't follow/bookmark every downvote because it would clutter up my followed page. I do make it a routine though to go through all of my downvotes every few months and undownvote things if necessary.

Comment: I don't use follow that much personally, but I do use bookmarks for essentially what you're describing (being notified of activity to 'review' it). I mentioned follow in case some people prefer the notification tray for this :)

Comment: I'll keep saying it until someone slaps me on the wrist, and I'll probably continue saying it afterwards, but most people won't leave comments nowadays because heavy-handed moderators believe that comments are third-rate and unnecessary. You can have the best intentions in commenting, in attempting to be a little more welcoming past the usual site-generated messages... but there's a handful on the moderating team who think comments are clutter, and will remove them. There's really no point anymore.

Comment: @Kaizerwolf On Arqade I haven't seen my advisory comments deleted until the post is either improved or deleted. Maybe it's a different case for you because you participate in other communities where the moderators have different views. Or maybe moderators haven't deleted my comments because I keep deleting them myself as soon as an improvement is made. If a comment discussion goes to while, I do delete the previous comment as I type the next, eventually moving it to chat if the notice appears.

Comment: I do think most people aren't offended by the closing of questions, i think previous me and that other dude are just a bit special in that department